# How to calculate the similarity of two electric waves

Tags: fft, algorithms

I have two electric signals from different sources and I think that are similar.
I have the FFT of the signals and I have their spectrums of frequency  in separate arrays. 
How should I proceed to find the percentual of similarity the two signals?

Comment: Can you put up the plots and/or data? That will go a long way.

Comment: Do these signals carry any meaning or information? Are they interpreted by any of the human senses? Can you think of a class of transformations that would alter the shape of the signals but would still preserve their similarity? It's not clear if what you need is just a squared error or something more complicated...

Answer (score 1):

You could measure the Cross-Correlation between the two signals.

Here's an almost identical thread, with a filling answer:

[How do I implement cross-correlation to prove two audio files are similar?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar)

Some general info on cross-correlation from wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation

Hope that helps.