# Signal compare - cross corelation in frequency domain matlab

Tags: matlab, frequency-spectrum, cross-correlation

I need compare two signals. Signals have simliar shapes but completely different values (as on picture):

[image]

So I think cross corelation in frequency domain should gave me a number that shows me how the signals are similar. But I have no idea how to do that in matlab.

Where I can find code to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cross-correlation will provide some information on the similarity of the two waveforms. See the function reference for [xcorr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html). Look into proper normalization so that the result is between something like 0 and 1 or -1 and 1. As a matter of fact, this is pretty well discussed in another stackexchange [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar).

As for frequency domain cross-correlation, I don't think that's what you want to do. Doing time-domain cross-correlation results in multiplication in the frequency domain, so you're looking to maximize the total energy in F(x)*F(y), where F(x) is the FFT of x.

Comment: Thanks for reply. xcorr returns me array but I need one number to describe similarity (I think it could be in one number). I was using also [corrcoef](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html) which returns me one number to decribe similarity but still not sure I can use that.

Can you describe step by step how to multiplicate time-domain cross-correlation results with frequency domain ? It's something like this: xcorr(x,y) * F(x)*F(y) ?